# Generic Text to Speech voice

Tags: text-to-speech

Is there (or can there ever be) a *generic* TTS voice, i.e. a voice that isn't tied to a certain language (such as English or German)?

I'm looking for a way to read street names in different countries with the *same* voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there is not (that I know of, or that a search turned up).

That is because most high-quality TTS engines rely on pre-recorded words being played out. For such a TTS to speak in the SAME voice in all languages, it would mean that the same person recorded his/her voice in all those languages. There are roughly 6500 languages today, and to record a dictionary in ONE language, it would take about a month. Therefore, to record all languages, it would take 541 years. That person would have died by then. *Note that this is an exaggeration: one does not need to record a dictionary word by word for a decent TTS.*

What is needed to accomplish this is fully computer generated speech. However, even this is split into dialects, as French puts emphasis on different letters then say, Spanish. If it weren't, then you might have a TTS engine speaking Fringlish.

Given your street names in different countries, the best solution would be to use [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/). It has alot of languages built in, and always sounds the same: robotic and without emotion. It can be called via command line, and hence can be used in almost any programming language.

If you know what country the street is in, you could have a database of what languages they speak in different countries. I once used the [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) database for this, and it works well. You could then call espeak with the text you want to speak, and the language. Geonames provides a daily [dump](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/), which you may download and extract the languages. You could then store the massive database on a server, such as [Dotcloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/). Alternatively, you could use their [API](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html), but that is limited to 30,000 uses a day.

If you do not know what language the country the street is in, you can go for more rough methods, that will not always work. Language detection. As majority of street names are real words in different countries, e.g. 'Main Street', you can run language detection, and figure out what language to use that way. I hear that [detectlanguage.com](http://detectlanguage.com/) is good for this.

So, while there is no existing method for this, you could make one yourself, without too much trouble.

Comment: Do they really need to record whole words? I thought they'd "just" need to record phonemes.